# Constante FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING obsoleta (deprecated)

Tags: php, filtro

A partir de PHP 8.1 la constante `FITER_SANITIZE_STRING` es declarada obsoleta. Lo mismo para `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED`. Es usada por algunos para ***sanear cadenas***; elimina etiquetas HTML, codifica comillas dentro del string y elimina ciertos caracteres especiales:

```
// captura de un input de formulario
$usuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

// Una variable:
$var = "Hola <title>mundo</title> 'SOE'";
echo filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // Hola mundo &#39;SOE&#39;
```

Al utilizarla, el intérprete genera la siguente advertencia:

> PHP Deprecated: Constant FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is deprecated in ...

¿Qué alternativa tienen los usuarios de esta constante?

[*] NOTAS -> PHP RFC: Deprecations for PHP 8.1 [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_8_1?do=#filter_sanitize_string)

Comment: Tal como dice su [manual de php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php), `Deprecated as of PHP 8.1.0, use htmlspecialchars() instead.`

Comment: La idea es agregarlo a la base de conocimiento, sobre todo para los que no leen la documentación ;)

Comment: @masterguru, no deberías hacer caso de ese tipo de comentarios, me consta que tu participación y respuestas son con el fin de ayudar; siempre habrá quienes estén de acuerdo contigo y otros que no y lo único que debes hacer es no tomarlo personal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La cuestión es que `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` no tiene ninguna razón de existir porque su funcionamiento es ambiguo.

Traducido desde PHP RFC: Deprecations for PHP 8.1 [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_8_1?do=#filter_sanitize_string):

> Este es un filtro dudoso y casi no tiene uso. Remueve NUL bytes,
> codifica comillas en HTML y remueve cualquier cosa entre `<` y `>` ... El
> filtro es peligroso y es una mala practica usarlo. 
> Al parecer se usa como un filtro que hace que una cadena sea segura mágicamente, sin ver antes en qué contexto será usada.

A pesar de tener un funcionamiento muy particular, era muy usado erróneamente para sanear entradas de usuario, y uno de los motivos que ayudaba a confundir es su nombre "**...sanitize_string**"

El uso de `htmlspecialchars()` **no es un reemplazo** del filtro, porque su uso es codificar caracteres HTML y no debe usarse para filtrar entradas de usuario.

```
> $var = "Hola <title>mundo</title> 'SOE'";
> echo htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES);
Hola &lt;title&gt;mundo&lt;/title&gt; &#039;SOE&#039;
```

Dos opciones que tienes serían:

1- Crear un filtro personalizado para la situación que se necesita.
El siguiente ejemplo, elimina todo excepto alfanuméricos o espacios:

```
> $var = "Hola <title>mundo</title> 'SOE'";
> echo preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/', '', $var);
Hola titlemundotitle SOE
```

2- Si la entrada del usuario es para Base de Datos, mejor usar consultas preparadas:

```
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
// ...
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE username=?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $usuario);
// ...
```

¿Y por qué no, las 2 cosas juntas? ;)